# Path not visible in d3.js - linegraph (But tooltip with mentioned points obtained in svg)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I was trying to draw a line graph along with bar graph with the same x and y axis with d3.js in my angularjs application. And the plot is not visible in page even though the svg element is obtained correctly with desired values. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient('bottom')
                .ticks(d3.time.hour, 2)
                .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'))
                .tickSize(5)
                .tickPadding(8);

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient('left')
                .tickPadding(8)
                .tickSize(5)
                .tickSubdivide(true);


            var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { return d.time; })
            .y(function(d) { return d.total; })
            .interpolate("linear");

            var svg =d3.select('#_id_ahuplot_container').append('svg')
                .attr('class', 'chart')
                //.attr('class', 'chart1')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)
                .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + [enter image description here][1]margin.top + ')');

            svg.selectAll('.chart')
                .data(data)
                .enter().append('rect')
                .attr('class', 'bar')
                .attr("fill",function(d,i){return colores(i)})
                .attr('x', function (d) {
                    return x(d.time);
                })
                .attr('y', function (d) {
                  return y(d.total) - margin.bottom;
                })
                .attr('width', function(d){
                return (x(d.time1)-x(d.time));
                })
                .attr('height', function (d) {
                  return ((height - margin.bottom) - y(d.total));
                })

                svg.append("path")
                .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
                .attr("stroke", "blue")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("fill", "none");

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'x axis')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ')')
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'y axis')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (-margin.left) + ')')
                .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: What is not visible, the line chart or the bar chart? Both? Do you get any error?

Comment: no errors found..i get the bar chart correctly but not the line

Comment: it would be great if share a fiddle